# Average word per sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, average

I was trying to get the average word per sentence of a file but I somehow get this error instead:

```
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Here is my code:

```
for line2 in csv:
    total_lines += 1
    total_words = len(line2.split())
    line_duplicate.append("Line %d has %d words" % (total_lines, total_words))
    sentence_count = len([char for char in line2 if char in sentence])
    line_duplicate.append("Line %d has %d Sentence/s" % (total_lines, sentence_count))                          
    avg =  total_words/sentence_count
    line_duplicate.append("Line %d has %d Average word per sentence/s" % (total_lines, avg))
```

Comment: Maybe one of your values does not contain what you think it does. Since you tried printing them before doing the calculations: what was the result?

Comment: what is the value of `sentence` ?

Comment: @ZainArshad mostly 1, 2 and 3 are the outputs in  the sentences

Comment: @usr2564301 mostly the output in sentence count is 1,2 or 3 and the total words counts all the words but when computing the average an error occurs, ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Comment: @Ajedrez  I asked what is the value of `sentence` variable that you are using...? what do you mean by `mostly 1, 2 and 3 are the outputs in the sentences `

Comment: @ZainArshad sentence = set(".") the loop then counts the periods per line

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is in this line:

```
sentence_count = len([char for char in line2 if char in sentence])
```

This is a logical error, you want to count the number of `.` in a string you but this list comprehension is just checking *words* in *line2* against your *sentence*. As no word would match against `.`, thus *sentence_count* becomes 0. Later in the code you are dividing it with *total_words*, so it throws *ZeroDivisionError*

What you actually needs to do is to check each separate character in *line2* against your *line2* variable. Replace it with this one:

```
sentence_count = len([char for word in line2 for char in word if char in sentence])
```

If you just want to count the number is `.` in *line2* and save it in *sentence_count*, you can just use `line2.count('.')`, more pythonic. So, you above line will reduce to this:

```
sentence_count = line2.count('.')
```

Comment: @Ajedrez if this solves your issue, then please mark this as Accepted answer. So that if anyone has similar issue they can see the solution as well, that how thinks work on SO :)